# Could someone explain me what is the difference between Hash#dig vs Hash#fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I'm trying to obtain a nested value in a hash. I've tried using `Hash#fetch` and `Hash#dig` but I don't understand how they should be combined.

My hash is as follows.

```
response = {
   "results":[
      {
         "type":"product_group",
         "value":{
            "destination":"Rome"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"product_group",
         "value":{
            "destination":"Paris"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"product_group",
         "value":{
            "destination":"Madrid"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried the following

```
response.dig(:results)[0].dig(:value).dig(:destination) #=> nil
response.dig(:results)[0].dig(:value).fetch('destination') #=> Rome
```

The desired return value is `"Rome"`. The second expression works but I would like to know if it can be simplified.

I'm using Ruby v2.5 and Rails v5.2.1.1.

Comment: In Ruby 2.4.5 I do not get the same results. `response.dig(:results)[0].dig(:value).dig(:destination)` gives "Rome", and `response.dig(:results)[0].dig(:value).fetch('destination')` raises `KeyError: key not found: "destination"`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using

ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux] and 
Rails 5.2.1.1

Comment: @DavidAldridge I've added a picture, hope now that the issue is more explanatory

Comment: Your question is straightforward, but I think it's muddled by I lot of extraneous information, which I believe accounts for the downvotes and vote to close. To highlight code in text, bracket it with backticks. To highlight a block of code indent it 4 spaces or select it and click the `{}` button. When giving an example assign a variable to all inputs (so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them) and always state the desired or expected return value (`"Rome"`). (cont...)

Comment: ... Lastly, in most SO questions you should say what you want to achieve (return `"Rome"`) without any reference to how it should be done. Then show what you have tried, which is to use `dig` and `fetch`. Some may deem your question as the statement of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). (There are exceptions, such as when you want to use a regular expression to extract information from a string, though you might invite other solutions that do not employ a regex.) If you don't like my edit please change it however you like. It's your question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) is not relevant here. That's because `fetch` is the same as [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) when, as here, `fetch` has only a single argument. So let's concentrate on `dig`.

A family of three `dig` methods were introduced in Ruby v2.3: [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig), [Array#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [OpenStruct#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-dig). An interesting thing about these methods is that they invoke each other (but that's not explained in the docs, not even in the examples). In your problem we can write:

```
response.dig(:results, 0, :value, :destination)
  #=> "Rome"
```

`response` is a hash so `Hash#dig` evaluates `response[:results]`. If it's value is `nil` then the expression returns `nil`. For example,

```
response.dig(:cat, 0, :value, :destination)
  #=> nil
```

In fact, `response[:results]` is an array:

```
arr = response[:results]
  #=> [{:type=>"product_group", :value=>{:destination=>"Rome"}},
  #    {:type=>"product_group", :value=>{:destination=>"Paris"}},
  #    {:type=>"product_group", :value=>{:destination=>"Madrid"}}]
```

`Hash#dig` therefore invokes `Array#dig` on `arr`, obtaining the hash

```
h = arr.dig(0)
  #=> {:type=>"product_group", :value=>{:destination=>"Rome"}}
```

`Array#dig` then invokes `Hash#dig` on `h`:

```
g = h.dig(:value)
  #=> {:destination=>"Rome"}
```

Lastly, `g` being a hash, `Hash#dig` invokes `Hash#dig` on `g`:

```
g.dig(:destination)
  #=> "Rome"
```

---

Caution needs to be exercised when using any of the `dig`'s. Suppose

```
arr = [[1,2], [3,[4,5]]]
```

and we wish to pull out the object that is now occupied by `4`. We could write either

```
arr[1][1][0]
  #=> 4
```

or

```
arr.dig(1,1,0)
  #=> 4
```

Now suppose `arr` were changed as follows:

```
arr = [[1,2]]
```

Then

```
arr[1][1][0]
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
arr.dig(1,1,0)
  #=> nil
```

Both are indicative of there being an error in our code, so raising an exception would be preferable to `nil` being returned, which may go unnoticed for some time.

Answer (score 2):

[`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

> `dig(key, ...) → object`
>
> Extracts the nested value specified by the sequence of key objects by calling `dig` at each step, returning `nil` if any intermediate step is `nil`.

[`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

> `fetch(key [, default] ) → obj`
>
> `fetch(key) {| key | block } → obj`
>
> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can't be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise a `KeyError` exception; if *default* is given, then that will be returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be run and its result returned.

That how difference looks at your example:

```
response = {
  "results": [
    {
      "type": 'product_group',
      "value": {
        "destination": 'Rome'
      }
    },
    {
      "type": 'product_group',
      "value": {
        "destination": 'Paris'
      }
    },
    {
      "type": 'product_group',
      "value": {
        "destination": 'Madrid'
      }
    }
  ]
}

response[:results].first.dig(:value, :destination) #=> "Rome"
response[:results].first.fetch(:value).fetch(:destination) #=> "Rome"
```